# Is $x=n^x$ solvable where $n>1$?

Tags: roots

Since the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=2^x$ (or $y=n^x$ for that matter, where $n>1$) do not intersect, is $x=2^x$ unsolvable? Or is there some kind of a really clever way to find a root?

P.S. I'm not too sure if this is the right tag to use.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=n^x=e^{x\ln n}$$
$$(-x\ln n)e^{-x\ln n}=-\ln n$$
$$-x\ln n=W(-\ln n)$$
$$x=-\frac{W(-\ln n)}{\ln n}$$
Since $W$ is real-valued on at least one branch when its argument is a small negative number (down to $-\frac1e$), $x=n^x$ has real solutions when $1<n\le e^{1/e}$.

Comment: Note the $W$ function is referring to the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).